# Nuxt auth module does not set loggedin user in store state

Tags: javascript, authentication, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am currently workin on Authentication functionality with the help of the Nuxt Auth Module.

On the frontend i am running Nuxt Js, and on the backend i am running Laravel 5.7

in nuxt.config.js i have set the auth settings:

```
  auth: {
  strategies: {
      local: {
          endpoints: {
              login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'access_token' },
              logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
              user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' },
          }
      },
       tokenRequired: true,
       tokenType: 'bearer',
  }
```

},

in my index.vue i have a form with the login method:

```
        <template>
    <div>
      <div>
        <b-container>
          <b-row no-gutters>
            <b-col col lg="12">

            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row no-gutters>
            <b-col col lg="12">
                <el-form :model="ruleForm" status-icon :rules="rules" ref="ruleForm" label-width="120px" class="demo-ruleForm" label-position="top">
                  <el-form-item label="Email" prop="email">
                    <el-input v-model="ruleForm.email" ></el-input>
                  </el-form-item>
                  <el-form-item label="Password" prop="password">
                    <el-input type="password" v-model="ruleForm.password" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
                  </el-form-item>
                  <el-form-item>
                    <el-button type="primary" @click="login">Inloggen</el-button>
                    <!--<el-button @click="resetForm('ruleForm2')">Reset</el-button>-->
                  </el-form-item>
                </el-form>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
        </b-container>
      </div>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            layout: 'login',
            data() {
                var validatePass = (rule, value, callback) => {
                    if (value === '') {
                        callback(new Error('Vul een wachtwoord in'));
                    } else {
                        callback();
                    }
                };
                return {
                    ruleForm: {
                        email: '',
                        password: '',
                    },
                    rules: {
                        password: [
                            { validator: validatePass, trigger: 'blur' }
                        ],
                        email: [
                            { required: true, message: 'Vul een email in', trigger: 'blur' },
                            { type: 'email', message: 'Vul een correct email adres in', trigger: ['blur'] }
                        ]
                    }
                };
            },
            methods: {

                async login() {
                    try {
                        await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
                            data: {
                                username: this.ruleForm.email,
                                password: this.ruleForm.password
                            }
                        }).then(() => {
                                this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard'})
                            })
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    </script>
```

When i try to login, the async function 'login' is being called. The user that corresponds with the username and password gets returned. 
The only problem i have, is that the when i look in the vuex state, auth.loggedIn stays false and the auth.user stays undefined.

I thought Nuxt Auth updates the state automatically, or am i missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution. I had to set the propertyname of the user endpoint to false

Old version

```
      endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'access_token' },
          logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'user' },
      }
```

New version

```
      endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'access_token' },
          logout: { url: 'logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: false },
      }
```

Now the user gets loaded in the state

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to fix this problem too, I've already set the propertyName to false, but I can't quite figure out how this connects to the api. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Had the same problem for two days. Using version 4.9.1. Your solution just solved it.

Comment: Neither of the options worked for me. It was working fine to me but all of sudden it stopped working

Comment: what does the JSON object that you send over look like I'm having a similar issue but I'm not sure if its due to what Im sending from my server