# Nuxt Auth middleware making empty request to the user endpoint

Tags: vue.js, authentication, flask, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to build a login module. I am using Nuxt auth to handle my login workflow and using flask for my RestAPI. I have set up the auth options in my `nuxt.config.js` as specified in the [docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/local.html#usage) and adapting the urls to my flask API as seen below:

```js
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: '/users/username/', method: 'post', propertyName: 'User' }
        },
        // tokenRequired: true,
        // tokenType: 'bearer'
        // autoFetchUser: true
      }
    }
  }
```

This here is my login component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="userLogin">
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="login.username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="text" v-model="login.password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      login: {
        username: 'newUser27',
        password: 'ninjaTurtles1!'
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async userLogin() {
      try {
        
        let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.login })
        
        console.log(response)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Now, the problem I am having is that when I hit on the login button to call submit the form and call my login function, the call to the login rout is successful, the request contains the user name and password from the form, and I get a response back. As shown in the pictures:

[Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj2gG.png) and [Request response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4Kc.png)

However, the call the user endpoint fails because the request body is empty, thus the server cant handle the request as seen in the picture below:
[Empty request body in call to user endpoint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR4V5.png)

I guess my question is if I had some kind of misconfiguration that is causing the request body to the user endpoint to be empty, thus failing to long in my user and keeping `this.$auth.loggedIn` and `this.$auth.user` false.

What I've tried to far:

- I tried switching the request in my API to a Post to see if that made any difference, as you can see in the picture above, it did not. Both get and post request have an empty body when they reach the API.
- I have tried setting the `propertyName` to `false` in the user endpoint [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557457/nuxt-auth-module-does-not-set-loggedin-user-in-store-state). Still get the same issue.
- I have tried using the `this.$auth.fetchUser()` method from my login function in the component, right after  `let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: this.login })`. [As recommended in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233773/how-to-refetch-user-in-vuex-with-nuxt-auth-module)r. Still get the same issue.

Any recommendation, or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You got error 500 on user endpoint request, that mean you have Internal Server Error, Can you send screenshot of user endpoint headers tab?

Answer (score 0):

Please set get request nuxt.config and also api endpoint.Thanks

```
 user: { url: '/users/username/', method: 'get', propertyName: 'User' }'
```

Comment: Hey Nazmul, thanks for the answer.
`tokenRequired` is true by default and my server already has 'Bearer' in the response. Otherwise, I would have 'Bearer Bearer <token>

Comment: Hello , can you please try user: { url: '/users/username/', method: 'get', propertyName: 'User' } 

try get method & also change your api to accept get request.

Answer (score 0):

According login endpoint, auth must receive `'token'` propertyName, but what showed in your response screenshot you received `'auth'` property as response, you should change your backend to return token property directly (not nested property) or change your login endpoint `propertyName`, you can check token set correctly by call

```
console.log( this.$auth.getToken('local') );
```